# Solving $i^z+i^{-z}=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

> How can I solve for complex number $z$? $$i^z+i^{-z}=0$$

My attempt

Let $p=iz\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi\right)$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$. Then the question becomes $$\exp(p)+\exp(-p)=0\implies \cosh(p)=0\implies \cos(ip)=0$$.
Suppose $z=x+iy$. Then, since $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$
$$\cos\left[\frac{\pi x}{2}(4n+1)+iy\frac{\pi}{2}(4n+1)\right]=0$$
How can I now solve this since here power series of cosine will lead to more complications and using the formula $\cos(z)=\cos(x)\cosh(y)-i\sin(x)\sinh(y)$ does not seem to end the complications here?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: You can use the fact that the zeros of $\cosh p$ are precisely the points $p_k=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi i$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @downvoter It would also be kind to explain after downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
   i^z+i^{-z} &= 0 \\
   i^z(i^z+i^{-z}) &= i^z(0) \\
   i^{2z} + 1 &= 0 \\
   i^{2z} &= -1
\end{align}

the rest should be clear